# attributes of all Objects are always empty after a command is executed

Tags: vb.net

I have a **KissDocument**.Class, from it i make Object(lets call it as obj1) and initialize his attributes from variables(let call it as **SetOfVariables**), which i declared before in my Form. after that i added obj1 in a List(lets call it **myList**), which is declared as Friend in my Form.

but when i change the **SetOfVariables** to another values, All Objects-Attributes in **myList** will be too changed.

in the following is **KissDocument**.Class:

```vb
Public Class KissDocument

    Public Docname As String
    Public Kisslist As List(Of String)
    Public ExcelList As List(Of String)
    Public DefaultList As List(Of String)

End Class
```

and here is the Form :

```vb
Public Class Form1

    '''''''''''''''''''   SetOfVariables ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim Kisslist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Dim ExcelList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Dim DefaultList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    Friend myList As List(Of KissDocument) = New List(Of KissDocument)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 
    End Sub

    'To Add New Object in the List myList
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Kisslist.Add("Id")
        Kisslist.Add("Name")

        ExcelList.Add("CusId")
        ExcelList.Add("Cusname")

        Dim obj1 As KissDocument = New KissDocument()
        obj1.Docname = InputBox("geben Sie bitte Doc Name ein ", "Eingabe", "Document")
        obj1.Kisslist = Kisslist
        obj1.ExcelList = ExcelList
        obj1.DefaultList = DefaultList

        myList.Add(obj1)

    End Sub

    ' to get the first Objects-attributes again :
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


        Kisslist.Clear()
        ExcelList.Clear()
        DefaultList.Clear()


        Dim KD As KissDocument = myList(0)
        Kisslist = KD.Kisslist
        ExcelList = KD.ExcelList
        DefaultList = KD.DefaultList

        'here are Kisslist,ExcelList,DefaultList empty   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  The Error appears here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only create one set of `List(Of String)` objects and you then assign those to every `KissDocument` object. Consider this. Let's say that you and I buy a pack of cards between us, so we share that one pack of cards. If I play with it and lose one of the Jokers, would you be surprised to see that your pack of cards was missing a Joker? Of course not, because there's only one pack of cards. Whatever I do to my pack of cards will be reflected in your pack because they are the same pack. The same goes for your `KissDocument` objects: they all share the same three `List(Of String)` objects so any change you make through one will be reflected in the others.

The solution starts with you defining your `KissDocument` class properly. For a start, use properties rather than fields. Secondly, all the collection properties should be read-only and set internally:

```vb
Public Class KissDocument

    Public Property DocName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property KissList As New List(Of String)
    Public ReadOnly Property ExcelList As New List(Of String)
    Public ReadOnly Property DefaultList As New List(Of String)

End Class
```

What that means is that calling code can now get the existing collection from the property, in order to get, add or remove items, but a whole new collection cannot be assigned to replace the existing one. That's how it works throughout the .NET Framework. Examples of such properties include `ComboBox.Items`, `ListBox.Items`, `Form.Controls`, `DataSet.Tables`, `DataTable.Columns`, `DataTable.Rows` and many, many more.

In your case, your `KissDocument` instances can't possibly share collections because each one creates its own. Your code to create and populate a `KissDocument` becomes this:

```vb
Private ReadOnly kissDocuments As New List(Of KissDocument)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim document As New KissDocument

    document.DocName = InputBox("geben Sie bitte Doc Name ein ", "Eingabe", "Document")
    document.KissList.Add("Id")
    document.KissList.Add("Name")
    document.ExcelList.Add("CusId")
    document.ExcelList.Add("CusName")

    kissDocuments.Add(document)
End Sub
```

Notice that the `kissDocuments` is appropriately named and declared `ReadOnly`, which is what all fields and properties should be if you don't need to assign a new object/value to them later. That's almost always the case for collections, where you may need to get, set, add and remove items from the collection but never replace the collection.